# Is it possible to perform two commands in the console MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Good afternoon
You can run two commands, one line in the console MongoDB?

for example:
  db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(); show dbs

but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show dbs` is a simple helper.

You should use: `db.getMongo().getDBs();`

So `db.getMongo().setSlaveOk();db.getMongo().getDBs()` should work.